# Why are these two functors equal?

Tags: category-theory, functors

From Mac Lane's Category theory:

Can someone explain why the box in red in the picture below is true?

By the first line in the proof, the diagram shown to be commutative is really:

$$S(1_{b'}, g) \circ S(f, 1_c) = S(f, 1_{c'}) \circ S(1_b, g)$$

But the equation to be proven is $M_{b}'g \circ L_c f = L_{c'} f \circ M_b g$, which when applying the functors and bifunctors of the proposition means we have to prove:

$$S(b', g) \circ S(f, c) = S(f, c') \circ S(b, g)$$

Why exactly are these arrows equal?

If $f : b \rightarrow b'$ then $S(f,c) $ and $S(f, 1_c)$ have the same domain and codomain but why are they the same arrow?

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $S(f,c)$ is a shorthand for $S(f,1_c)$, since $c$ is used interchangeably with its identity morphism, as mentioned in the first line of the proof.

Comment: But if $f : b \rightarrow b'$, then $L_cf : L_cb \rightarrow L_cb'$ and $S(-, c)(f) = S(f,c) = L_cf : L_cb \rightarrow L_cb'$.  Then is $S(f,c)$ still shorthand notation for $S(f, 1_c)$?  Because it seems that one is the functor $L_c$ and the other is a bifunctor from $B \times C \rightarrow D$?

Comment: Yes, $S(f,c)$ is always a shorthand for $S(f,1_c)$.  I'm not sure what you mean by your second sentence.  We are assuming here that the bifunctor $S$ has the property that $S(-,c)=L_c$, where $S(-,c)$ denotes the functor that sends an object $b$ to $S(b,c)$ and a morphism $f$ to $S(f,1_c)$.

Comment: So $S(f,c)$ **must** denote $S(f,1_c)$ for $S(f,c)$ to be a morphism in $D$ because the notation $S(x,y)$ is an object while $S(f, f')$ is an arrow?

Comment: Yes, the notation $S(f,c)$ has no meaning unless you define one for it, since $f$ is an arrow but $c$ is an object.

Comment: @EricWofsey : the standard meaning would probably be $S(\cdot, c)$ (a functor) evaluated at $f$. But the (standard) definition of $S(\cdot , c)$ would make $S(f,c) = S(f, id_c)$ anyway so there's very little ambiguity here